# How do I prevent a component from rendering twice?

Tags: reactjs

I want to initialize a component but it keeps rendering all the time.

According to [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate) I use `React.memo` but that doesn't prevent the component from rerendering: console.log("re-render") prints more than once. How do I make that component exactly static no matter what happens above in the tree?

```
const Canvas = React.memo((props) => {
    const context = useContext(Context);
    const width = "500%";
    const height = "500%";

    const count = useRef(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        context.initCanvas("c");
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []); //runs only once on mount

    console.log("re-render"); //outputs all the time when I cange something above in the tree.

    return (
        <>
            <canvas
                style={{border: "1px dashed black", margin: "10px"}}
                id="c"
                width={width}
                height={height}
            >
            </canvas>
        </>
    );
});
```

Comment: you want it to rerender, no? I mean you want to actually show the increased counter?

Comment: No, the counter is just to show if it's rendered again. I want it to be executed once and never again.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

> Even if an ancestor uses React.memo or shouldComponentUpdate, a rerender will still happen starting at the component itself using useContext.

Therefore, the component wil rerender because of the fact we are using useContext.

There is a discussion in github where 3 solutions are propoosed for this case. Here is the [link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156#issuecomment-474590693).

Comment: I can not use any of these.  I need the exact context in there (can't split context and cant remove context...).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are incrementing the `count` here:

```
 Count: {count.current++}
```

If you are only displaying a value you should not mutate it on the render.

You can handle this increment in other part of the code, maybe write a method that increment your `counter` and just apply it when its necessary. Other solution is to create a useEffect that will handle this counter.

In this case you are incrementing your value very time because you are making this operation on the `render` method.

Comment: That's the plan to increment it there. I do it to see if it's rendered again (thus counting up). I added comment to the code snip

Comment: And if you delete this part it continue rendering infinitely?

Comment: No. The part is just there so it gets executed when the component is rendered. It should always display a "1" but when I do things above in the tree, the count gets up which tells me, that the component gets mutated which it should not.

Comment: use a console log or something to keep track of renders, mutating a ref seems like a very unreliable way to detect renders.

Comment: @BrianThompson how?

Comment: Just above the `return`, add `console.log('re-render')`

Comment: I have added that console.log and removed the count.current++ It does re-render multiple times. See edit in question